# Invalid column name in row_number() function

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, sqlserver

Why am I getting this error?

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'Id'.

```
SELECT
    (L.Id) as 'SubscriberKey',
    L.ID__c as 'ID_C',
    L.Email as 'EmailAddr',
    L.Gender__c as 'Gender',
    L.Count_ID as 'Count_ID'

    from (
        select 
        (T.Id) as 'SubscriberKey',
        T.ID__c as 'ID_C',
        T.Email as 'EmailAddr',
        T.Gender__c as 'Gender',
        row_number() over (order by T.CreatedDate desc) as 'Count_ID'

        from ent.Lead_Salesforce T

        WHERE 
        T.Email <> ''
        and T.Email is not null
        and (T.ID__c<>' ' or T.ID__c Is NOT Null) 
    ) L
```

I'm trying to imitate `AUTO_INCREMENT` using `row_number()`

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove `as '<rename>'` from the second select.
Otherwise, the first select cannot find this column names.